# Roots of complex numbers - The devision algorithm (polynomials over R and C)

Tags: complex-numbers

Question:
Find all the (possibly complex) roots of the given
polynomials.

$f(x)= x^4 - 2x^3 -2x^2 + 8x -8$

One of the roots is $1-i$

My answer:
Since the coefficients of $f(x)$ are real , it follows that $1+i$ is also a root of $f(x)$. Therefore $g(x) = (x-1-i)(x-1+i)$ is a factor of $f(x)$.

Now I have to use long division to determine the accompanying factor of $f(x)$, then identify a useful grouping of the terms in the polynomial. I am stuck at the last part of my answer. What do I need to divide by what to get that accompanying factor? Do I have to use long division a second time?

Comment: I think you mean 'it follows that $1+i$ is also a root'.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I see that is a mistake.Thank you. But then I still don't know how to continue with the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. You've established that $1 - i$ and $1+i$ are roots of $f(x)$ and thus that there is a polynomial $h(x)$ such that 
\begin{equation}
f(x) = (x-1-i)(x-1+i)h(x).
\end{equation}
Hence
\begin{equation}
h(x) = \frac{f(x)}{(x-1-i)(x-1+i)},
\end{equation}
and so we need to divide $f$ by $(x-1-i)(x-1+i)$. Using long division (or otherwise) one obtains
\begin{equation}
h(x) = (x-2)(x+2).
\end{equation}
We can conclude then that $1\pm i$ and  $\pm 2$ are roots of $f(x)$. Moreover, by the fundamental theorem of algebra, $f(x)$ has exactly $4$ roots and so these are all the roots of $f$.